# Minimum permission to execute sp_changedbowner SP

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, permissions, amazon-rds, aws

Is `db_owner` permission sufficient to execute `sp_changedbowner`?

I'm looking to change the database owner of a RDS SQL instance. I'm the owner of the DB, and still couldn't execute `sp_changedbowner` as master user.

I would like to know what the minimum permissions are to execute `sp_changedbowner` or `ALTER AUTHORIZATION` commands.

Comment: Why do you need to change the database owner in RDS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*<sub>[Community wiki answer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-authorization-transact-sql#permissions):</sub>*

From [`ALTER AUTHORIZATION` (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-authorization-transact-sql#permissions):

> Requires `TAKE OWNERSHIP` permission on the entity. If the new owner is not the user that is executing this statement, also requires either, 1) `IMPERSONATE` permission on the new owner if it is a user or login; or 2) if the new owner is a role, membership in the role, or `ALTER` permission on the role; or 3) if the new owner is an application role, `ALTER` permission on the application role.

There may be additional considerations in the AWS RDS world.

Note that [`sp_changedbowner`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-changedbowner-transact-sql) is deprecated in favour of `ALTER AUTHORIZATION`. The `sp_changedbowner` documentation says:

> Requires `TAKE OWNERSHIP` permission on the database. If the new owner has a corresponding user in the database, requires `IMPERSONATE` permission on the login, otherwise requires `CONTROL SERVER` permission on the server.

Answer (score 1):

I will show this with a demo.
Most likely in your case you are missing `CONTROL SERVER` privilege.

A good reading about this topic will be:

[Basic SQL Server Security concepts: ownership, CONTROL, TAKE OWNERSHIP](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/lcris/2009/08/11/basic-sql-server-security-concepts-ownership-control-take-ownership/) by Laurentiu Cristofor

Running following code under a account with sysadmin privilege.

```
USE [master];
GO
--creating a new database
CREATE DATABASE [testpermission];
GO
--creating a SQL login
CREATE LOGIN [ownerone] WITH PASSWORD=N'ownerone', DEFAULT_DATABASE=[master], CHECK_EXPIRATION=OFF, CHECK_POLICY=OFF;
GO
--making the new user owner of database
USE [master]
GO
ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON DATABASE::testpermission TO ownerone;  
GO
--checking the new owner
SELECT suser_sname(owner_sid) FROM sys.databases WHERE NAME = 'testpermission';
GO
```

You will see the new owner name is `ownerone`.

Now creating another login.

```
USE [master]
GO
CREATE LOGIN [newowner] WITH PASSWORD=N'newowner', DEFAULT_DATABASE=[master], CHECK_EXPIRATION=OFF, CHECK_POLICY=OFF;
GO
```

Now login as `ownerone` and execute following statement to give ownership to `newowner`.

```
ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON DATABASE::testpermission TO newowner;
```

You get following error message:

> Msg 15151, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Cannot find the principal
>   'newowner', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.

Give `ownerone` login `CONTROL SERVER` privilege.

```
USE [master]
GO
GRANT CONTROL SERVER TO [ownerone];
GO
```

Repeat following and now you will be able to change ownership to `newowner`.

```
ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON DATABASE::testpermission TO newowner;
```

Clean up code.

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_delete_database_backuphistory @database_name = N'testpermission'
GO
USE [master]
GO
DROP DATABASE [testpermission]
GO
DROP LOGIN [newowner]
GO
DROP LOGIN [ownerone]
GO
```